# Randomize rotation of each instance (linked) independently using Geo Nodes

Tags: transforms, geometry-nodes

[image]Hello,

I'm completely new to blender and Im trying to randomize the rotation of some instances ("on points") that are flying around an object, similar to the fireflies effect tutorials on youtube. However instead of spheres, Im using instances (Star shapes) and would like them to also rotate around themselves independently of one another randomly as they are flying.

I noticed there was an attribute on older versions of Blender called "Randomize" could have worked. For now Im using "Random Value" which does the trick somewhat, but all the stars rotation seems to be linked to one another and I dont want that.

Is there a way to get them to rotate independently from each other;

Thanks!

Short Video: https://streamable.com/43o80o

Answer (score 1):

you can use this node setup:

[image]

you setup looks pretty the same. Maybe you should provide your blend file - maybe there is something wrong in your driver or other problems.

Comment: alrighty, managed to find a solution. Instead of using the previous nodes setup for rotation I had, I added a "Combine XYZ" node connected to "Random Value" (Vector) node plugged into the instance on points node. Now the everything seems to be a lot smoother and randomized. I think. Thanks

Comment: Switch "Random Value" node to "Vector" node, otherwise you will get only a small subset of all possible rotations: https://i.imgur.com/s11Gs9w.png

Comment: @MarkusvonBroady: oh yeah, you are right! thanks for that improvement.